# Eclipse4 - Application Model and Core Expressions definitions

Tags: menu, eclipse-plugin, expression, perspective

In Application.e4xmi I have two perspectives:

```
 ...  
  <children xsi:type="advanced:PerspectiveStack" xmi:id="_ySFusPeXEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.perspectivestack.main">
  <children xsi:type="advanced:Perspective" xmi:id="_83bVsPeXEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.perspective.testmanager" label="Test manager">
  ...
  <children xsi:type="advanced:Perspective" xmi:id="_bDA4oPeaEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.perspective.configurator" label="Configurator">
  ...
```

and a main menu with two items:

```
<mainMenu xmi:id="_xanVgPfWEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.menu.0">
  <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_22vnAPfWEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.handledmenuitem.uno" label="uno" command="_LFFTsPhHEeK44MdhTvpdlg">
    <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_28cw8PfXEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" coreExpressionId="com.myapplication.ui.perspectiveselected.testmanager"/>
  </children>
  <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_49obAPfWEeKXHJPsnYiiYQ" elementId="com.myapplication.ui.handledmenuitem.due" label="due" command="_NXT1APhHEeK44MdhTvpdlg">
    <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_ZP4lgPhHEeK44MdhTvpdlg" coreExpressionId="com.myapplication.ui.perspectiveselected.configurator"/>
  </children>
  </mainMenu>
```

The menu item "com.myapplication.ui.handledmenuitem.uno" has to be shown when perspective "com.myapplication.ui.perspective.testmanager" is shown.
   The menu item "com.myapplication.ui.handledmenuitem.due" has to be shown when perspective "com.myapplication.ui.perspective.configurator" is shown.

So that, I defined in plugin.xml:

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
      <definition
            id="com.myapplication.ui.perspectiveselected.testmanager">
         <with
               variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
            <equals
                  value="com.myapplication.ui.perspective.testmanager">
            </equals>
         </with>
      </definition>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
      <definition
            id="com.myapplication.ui.perspectiveselected.configurator">
         <with
               variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
            <equals
                  value="com.myapplication.ui.perspective.configurator">
            </equals>
         </with>
      </definition>
   </extension>
```

IT DOESN'T WORK !! (menu items are shown always)
   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have applied  on the definition itself. Create a new command and register it with your menu and then write your expression on it.
Example:

```
  <command
       commandId=" "
       label=" "
       mnemonic="A">
     <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
        <with
             variable="">
           <equals
                value="1">
           </equals>
       </with>
    </visibleWhen>
 </command>
```